# Дозагрузка картинок через один input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Никак не могу решить задачу. Обгуглился пытался придумать какойто костыль но все попытки не увенчались успехом. Скрипт выводит пользователю на экран загруженные ним картинки. input для этих целей используется один. Соответственно когда пользователь использует input повторно, то его value сбрасывается. И на сервер приходит только последний результат. Пытался добавлять еще один инпут и ссылаться на него, но потерял последующее отображение картинок. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

HTML

```
<form action="/service/sdelat-spravky-na-avto" id="img-upload-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <p>
        <label for="upload_imgs" class="button hollow">Загрузите ваши фото +</label>
        <input style="display: none;" class="show-for-sr" type="file" id="upload_imgs" name="upload_imgs[]" multiple>
    </p>
    <div class="quote-imgs-thumbs quote-imgs-thumbs--hidden" id="img_preview" aria-live="polite"> 
    Тут отображается превью загруженных картинок. 
    </div>

</form>
```

JS

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
                $(function () {
                    $(".spoiler").hide();

                    $(".spoiler-link").on("click", function (e) {
                        var idSpoiler = $(this).attr("href"),
                            classSelect = "spoiler-link--active";

                        $(this).toggleClass(classSelect);
                        $(idSpoiler).slideToggle(200);

                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                });


                var imgUpload = document.getElementById('upload_imgs')
                    , imgPreview = document.getElementById('img_preview')
                    , imgUploadForm = document.getElementById('img-upload-form')
                    , totalFiles
                    , previewTitle
                    , previewTitleText
                    , img;

                imgUpload.addEventListener('change', previewImgs, false);
                imgUploadForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert('Images Uploaded! (not really, but it would if this was on your website)');

                    $.ajax({
                        url: $(this).attr('action'),
                        method: "POST",
                        data: new FormData(this),
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        contentType: false,
                        cache: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success:function(dd) {
                            console.log('log: ' + dd);
                        }
                    });

                }, false);

                function previewImgs(event) {
                    totalFiles = imgUpload.files.length;

                    if(!!totalFiles) {
                        imgPreview.classList.remove('quote-imgs-thumbs--hidden');
                        previewTitle = document.createElement('p');
                        previewTitle.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
                        //previewTitleText = document.createTextNode(totalFiles + ' Ваш документ.');
                        previewTitleText = document.createTextNode('Загруженные документы.');
                        previewTitle.appendChild(previewTitleText);
                        imgPreview.appendChild(previewTitle);
                    }

                    for(var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
                        img = document.createElement('img');
                        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]);
                        img.classList.add('img-preview-thumb');
                        imgPreview.appendChild(img);
                    }
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: Не понятно в чём вопрос. Вы только рассказали как всё работает.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev как не сбрасывать value input-а. Сделать так что бы он добавлял в массив inputa все последующие файлы.

Comment: Попробуйте составлять объект FormData самостоятельно или при изменении поля делать append в FormData. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Comment: @PavelGrishaev загрузка файлов происходит после нажатия кнопки отправить. Превью это blob src. Я пробовал делать append создавая следующий input с другим id, меняя var imgUpload. Но не работала. Спасибо, сейчас я понял что всё усложнил. Вы натолкнули меня на мысль, я попробую добавлять идентичный input скрывая старый и удаляя его id. Может получится. )

Comment: Я имел в виду метод FormData.append() , а не создание второго элемента. Весь FormData можно строить самостоятельно. И зачем вам морока с id, проще по классу делать, не придётся уникальность соблюдать.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev 
$('.show-for-sr').css("display", "none");
$('#upload_imgs').removeAttribute('id');
$('.nextinput').append('<input class="show-for-sr" type="file" id="upload_imgs" name="upload_imgs[]" multiple>'); 
Но чтото не работает..

Comment: @PavelGrishaev идентификатор чтобы стилизовать label который ведёт на скрытый input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя 21 час страдания проблема была решена таким образом.

```
var data = new FormData();

    $('#upload_imgs').change(function(ev) {
        $.each(ev.currentTarget.files, function (key, value) {
                data.append('files[]', value);
        });
    });

$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    method: "POST",
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function() {
        console.log('log: ', data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь я все верно понял. Сами картинки можно забрать с `src` имейджов.

```js
$(function() {
  function readURL(input) {
    $(input.files).each(function(i, el) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $("#im").append(`<div class='d-flex'><img src=${e.target.result}><button class='remove'>X<\/button><\/div>`);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
    });
  }

  $("#imgInput").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
  });
  
  $("#im").on('click','.remove',function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: auto;
  height: 80px;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Добавить изображение(-я)</span><input type="file" name="bn" id="imgInput" multiple>
<div id="im"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот попробуйте на локальном сервере такой index.html и посмотрите что отправляется в запросе:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="" id="img-upload-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <p>
            <label for="upload_imgs" class="button hollow">Загрузите ваши фото +</label>
            <input style="display: none;" class="show-for-sr" type="file" id="upload_imgs" name="upload_imgs[]" multiple>
        </p>
        <div class="quote-imgs-thumbs quote-imgs-thumbs--hidden" id="img_preview" aria-live="polite"> 
        Тут отображается превью загруженных картинок. 
        </div>

        <button>Отправить</button>

    </form>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".spoiler").hide();

            $(".spoiler-link").on("click", function (e) {
                var idSpoiler = $(this).attr("href"),
                    classSelect = "spoiler-link--active";

                $(this).toggleClass(classSelect);
                $(idSpoiler).slideToggle(200);

                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });


        var imgUpload = document.getElementById('upload_imgs')
            , imgPreview = document.getElementById('img_preview')
            , imgUploadForm = document.getElementById('img-upload-form')
            , totalFiles
            , previewTitle
            , previewTitleText
            , img;

        var formData = new FormData();
        var filesArray = [];

        imgUpload.addEventListener('change', previewImgs, false);
        imgUploadForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Images Uploaded! (not really, but it would if this was on your website)');

            filesArray.forEach(( file, index )=> formData.set( `upload_imgs[${index}]`, file ) );


            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                method: "POST",
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success:function(dd) {
                    console.log('log: ' + dd);
                }
            });

        }, false);

        function previewImgs(event) {
                Array.from(imgUpload.files).forEach( file => filesArray.push( file ) );


            totalFiles = imgUpload.files.length;

            if(!!totalFiles) {
                imgPreview.classList.remove('quote-imgs-thumbs--hidden');
                previewTitle = document.createElement('p');
                previewTitle.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
                //previewTitleText = document.createTextNode(totalFiles + ' Ваш документ.');
                previewTitleText = document.createTextNode('Загруженные документы.');
                previewTitle.appendChild(previewTitleText);
                imgPreview.appendChild(previewTitle);
            }

            for(var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
                img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]);
                img.classList.add('img-preview-thumb');
                imgPreview.appendChild(img);
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Тут FormData составляется полностью самостоятельно, а не созданием лишних полей формы.

Comment: Если стоит data: formData то картинки не загружаются. Если по старому data: new FormData(this), то работает по старому.